# apsw.Connection has no attribute enableloadextension

Tags: python, macos, pip, homebrew, apsw

I have installed Python 2.7.9 on Mac OS X Yosemite with Homebrew and I have also installed apsw 3.8.8.2-r1 via the bundled pip.

However, even though the apsw module is found, I cannot seem to be able to run my application, as if fails with the an `AttributeError`.

```
AttributeError: type object 'apsw.Connection' has no attribute 'enableloadextension'
```

I am new to OS X, but not new to Python development. I have no idea what could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you have to compile apsw from source to enable several extensions as the apsw site [states](http://rogerbinns.github.io/apsw/download.html#easy-install-pip-pypi).

Comment: Can you post the build commands that worked for you?  I have been trying to get `apsw` to work on Capitan and the following command does not work for me (i.e I'm getting your original error).  `python setup.py fetch --all build --enable-all-extensions install`

Comment: @Castrona The command you show works for me with Python installed via Homebrew.